# How would I split a gif into separate rows and columns

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I have a gif that I wish to split evenly into 8 columns and 4 rows and into 32 separate files, is it possible to do this in photoshop or should I be looking into a different application? And this is possible how would I go about doing it?

Comment: You could use the slice tool to do it, then File > Export > Save for Web (legacy), select all the slices and set them to GIF.

Comment: This is the answer, thank you, please post this as an answer so I can accept it, you've helped me greatly

Comment: OK, I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the slice tool to do it, then do *File > Export > Save for Web (legacy)*, select all the slices and set them to GIF. This works with static or animated GIFs.

An example

[image]

Cut up gifs exported to a folder

[image]